# cookie support in cordova official documentation

Tags: cordova, cookies

I've read many question asking if there is support for cookies in cordova/phone gap, like the following

- [PhoneGap/Cordova: How to get use cookies (iOS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220244/phonegap-cordova-how-to-get-use-cookies-ios) - answer to user localstorage
- [Phonegap not propagating the session cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659905/phonegap-not-propagating-the-session-cookie) - not answered, would be nice to know answer to point 1) and 2)
- http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/authentication_session_cookies_in_android - from the community of phone gap: There is no direct Build support for this at the moment.

By a search with google I can't find out the documentation of cordova where it states if there is no support for cookies. Where should I look about it? 
one of the most significative link is this one [Handling cookies in PhoneGap/Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349237/handling-cookies-in-phonegap-cordova) in which we can read 
"

- In JavaScript cookies can be set with document.cookie = ..., **but they are not saved in PhoneGap and lost**. Before firing xhr requests it works.
- Cookies can be retrieved after xhr request with xhr.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie'). But only when actually set on the server. Unfortunately, jQuery strips the "Cookie" header."

I don't want to know how to store such information, I understood and used local storage just for a test in my application but I want to understand if the support for cookies is stated to be provided or not in the official documentation of cordova since it seems I can not find it..

any clue is really appreciated.. thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the official documentation cookie support was never stated. Their reference in the Cordova JIRA item [CB-8026](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8026) that in Android third-party cookies are enabled.

Currently [there is work](https://github.com/cordova/cordova-discuss/blob/master/FAQ.md) in the Cordova team (as of May 2015) to clarify that point in the documentation

Comment: unfortunately it was never stated either to be supported either to be not supported. It's to wide to say support was never stated.. This is anyhow a good point of start, since we are talking about a cross-platform tool there should be a general statement for all the supported platform that allow users to understand if it is still the case to trust cookie usage or not.. anyhow +1

Comment: The currently work to clarify that exists in Cordova team. Update my answer.